# Pinotdb in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-eks, apache-pinot

I'm new working with AWS EKS and Pinotdb library in python.

Can someone help me?

I already have an AWS EKS cluster with Apache Pinot installed in it.

I want with a AWS lambda query the data and tables that already comes with the quick pinot start.

the code I started working is:

```py
from pinotdb import connect

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    conn = connect(host='MyHost', port=8099)
    curs = conn.cursor()
    curs.execute("select * from airlineStats air limit 10")
```

but this error always appears:

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "[Errno -2] Name or service not known",
  "errorType": "ConnectError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 7, in lambda_handler\n    curs.execute(\"select * from airlineStats air limit 10\")\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/pinotdb/db.py\", line 57, in g\n    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/pinotdb/db.py\", line 490, in execute\n    **kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/httpx/_client.py\", line 1149, in post\n    extensions=extensions,\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/httpx/_client.py\", line 821, in request\n    return self.send(request, auth=auth, follow_redirects=follow_redirects)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/httpx/_client.py\", line 912, in send\n    history=[],\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/httpx/_client.py\", line 939, in _send_handling_auth\n    history=history,\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/httpx/_client.py\", line 973, in _send_handling_redirects\n    response = self._send_single_request(request)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/httpx/_client.py\", line 1009, in _send_single_request\n    response = transport.handle_request(request)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/httpx/_transports/default.py\", line 218, in handle_request\n    resp = self._pool.handle_request(req)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py\", line 130, in __exit__\n    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/httpx/_transports/default.py\", line 77, in map_httpcore_exceptions\n    raise mapped_exc(message) from exc\n"
  ]
}

Function Logs
START RequestId: f7dba952-efb5-4435-84cd-aaf2c8a9190d Version: $LATEST
[ERROR] ConnectError: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 7, in lambda_handler
    curs.execute("select * from airlineStats air limit 10")
  File "/opt/python/pinotdb/db.py", line 57, in g
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python/pinotdb/db.py", line 490, in execute
    **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python/httpx/_client.py", line 1149, in post
    extensions=extensions,
  File "/opt/python/httpx/_client.py", line 821, in request
    return self.send(request, auth=auth, follow_redirects=follow_redirects)
  File "/opt/python/httpx/_client.py", line 912, in send
    history=[],
  File "/opt/python/httpx/_client.py", line 939, in _send_handling_auth
    history=history,
  File "/opt/python/httpx/_client.py", line 973, in _send_handling_redirects
    response = self._send_single_request(request)
  File "/opt/python/httpx/_client.py", line 1009, in _send_single_request
    response = transport.handle_request(request)
  File "/opt/python/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 218, in handle_request
    resp = self._pool.handle_request(req)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/opt/python/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 77, in map_httpcore_exceptions
    raise mapped_exc(message) from exc
END RequestId: f7dba952-efb5-4435-84cd-aaf2c8a9190d
```

My lambda is configured with a role with:
eks:*
lambda:*
ec2:*

and it's configure with the VPC and security groups as the EKS cluster has.

Can someone help me?